# Fastest synchronization technique

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, runnable, callable

Following is a rather common scenario of accessing a common resource, either in a sequential (single-threaded) or a concurrent (multi-threaded) way, for which the fastest technique is needed.

More specifically (see sample source code below), a `Manager` class creates some instances of a `Runnable` (or `Callable`) class (`Handler`) with a common resource (a `Store` object). The `Manager` class is actually subclassed and its `execute()` method overridden to run the handlers sequentially in the same thread, or in multiple threads (e.g., via an `ExecutorService`), depending on the subclass implementation.

My question is, what would be the fastest (less overhead) way of synchronizing access to the shared `Store` object inside the `run` (or `call()`) method of each `Handler` object, especially taking into account that, for single-threaded access, that synchronization is redundant (but has to be there, because there are also multi-threaded `Manager` subclass implementations).

Would, for instance, a `synchronized (this.store) {this.store.process()}` block be better than, say, using a `Lock` object from `java.util.concurrent`, before and after calling `this.store.process()`? Or would a separate `synchronized` method inside `Handler` for each store access be faster? For example, instead of calling `this.store.process()`, run something like

```
private synchronized void processStore()
{
    this.store.process();
}
```

Following is the (sample) source code.

```
public class Manager
{
    public Manager()
    {
        Store store = new Store(); // Resource to be shared
        List<Handler> handlers = createHandlers(store, 10);

        execute(handlers);
    }

    List<Handler> createHandlers(Store store, int count)
    {
        List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<Handler>();

        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            handlers.add(new Handler(store));
        }

        return handlers;
    }

    void execute(List<Handler> handlers)
    {
        // Run handlers, either sequentially or concurrently 
    }
}

public class Handler implements Runnable // or Callable
{
    Store store; // Shared resource

    public Handler(Store store)
    {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public void run() // Would be call(), if Callable
    {
        // ...
        this.store.process(); // Synchronization needed
        // ...
        this.store.report();  // Synchronization needed
        // ...
        this.store.close();   // Synchronization needed
        // ...
    }       
}

public class Store
{
    void process() {}
    void report()  {}
    void close()   {}
}
```

Comment: What of "process", "report", "close" can be executed in parallel? What happens if one thread calls "close" while the others still work. This all are basis for evaluation how you should use synchronization/lock. What are the common datastructures within Store. 
There cannot be a general answer if it is unclear what the common data is.

Comment: The question refers to synchronizing on the store object, or on the Handle object (e.g., the processStore() method), so any data shared among the process(), report() and close() methods, or whether these methods execute in parallel, should be covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: CAS synchronization < `synchronized` < `Lock` in terms of speed. Of course this will depend on the degree of contention and your operating system. I would suggest you try each and determine which is the fastest for your need.

Java also performs [lock elision](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10185/) to avoid locking on objects that are only visible to one thread.

Comment: ... where `<` means "greater than" :)

Comment: Yes, I also took '<' for 'faster than'! :-)

Comment: Here is a brief and nice comparison between synchronized() and Lock: http://blog.rapleaf.com/dev/2011/06/16/java-performance-synchronized-vs-lock/

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I was going for the "takes *less* time". :)

Answer (score 1):

As my knowledge if your app run or will run at cluster mode then synchronized will not work ( different JVM) so Lock will be the only option.

If the common resource  is queue then you can use ArrayBlockingQueue, if not then start synchronized access for this resource.